# Cancel command with before_invoke without printing error message (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot, which I would like to prevent from running unless a certain parameter is filled.

Here is the bot's current code:

```py
@bot.before_invoke
async def checkguild(message):
    command = message.command
    if command != 'settings':
        if not message.guild.id in globaldb.servers_setup.val:
            for required_setting in REQUIRED_SETTINGS:  # Iterates through the required settings to make sure they're all defined.
                if not get_guild_db(message.guild).settings.has(required_setting):
                    # Prevent command from running, and call the on_command_error function instead of just throwing an error.
            globaldb.set('servers_setup', globaldb.servers_setup.val + [message.guild.id])
            globaldb.save()  # Otherwise add the server to the database as set up.
```

I would like to do as the comment in the middle says,

`# Prevent command from running, and call the on_command_error function instead of just throwing an error.`

but how would I do that? (Check answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the error system provided by discord.ext.commands, we must raise its `CommandError` Exception.

This would be implemented like so:

```py
@bot.before_invoke
async def checkguild(message):
    command = message.command
    if command != 'settings':
        if not message.guild.id in globaldb.servers_setup.val:
            for required_setting in REQUIRED_SETTINGS:  # Iterates through the required settings to make sure they're all defined.
                if not get_guild_db(message.guild).settings.has(required_setting):
                    # Prevent command from running, and call the on_command_error function instead of just throwing an error.
                    raise discord.ext.commands.CommandError(f'Before using this bot, please set the `{required_setting}` setting.')
            globaldb.set('servers_setup', globaldb.servers_setup.val + [message.guild.id])
            globaldb.save()  # Otherwise add the server to the database as set up.
```

Comment: Note for OP: `CommandError` is pretty much the base class for all discord.ext errors, if you catch it with `isinstance` all other errors will be catched too (like `CommandNotFound`, `MissingRequiredArgument`, etc), you should make your own custom error (inherited from `CommandError`) and raise that instead.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Thanks, I didn't know that!